# Flutter return to home page

Tags: dart, flutter

I have made an app that has quite some routing in it, pushing multiple fullscreen dialogs after each other. But from one dialog I want to close all and return to the homepage. How can I do that?

I don't want to push the homepage again, because then I have all these dialogs still in my navigation history. Is `pushReplacement` the right way? It doesn't seem to be because it only deletes the last entry in the navigation history, so if i press back, i get to the second last dialog...

Answer (score 13):

Use `popUntil` to go back to the point you want. If it's the Home page, this should work:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

Answer (score 13):

In case you don't use named routing:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

Answer (score 3):

For Homepage it will work from any other page.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```