# When pressing the logout button I want to pop all the screen and logout and show the Login and Register page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
 void logOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

In this case, if I'm in the home page, then logout function works as expected. After getting into few more pages using named routes and then I try to logout through the button, it doesn't work. Logout happens but the page that I'm currently on stays there. Only when I go back the screen pops and goto to Login/Register page. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter return to home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556259/flutter-return-to-home-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseAuth doesn't handle navigation for you, after the above line (    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()) you need to navigate the user back to whatever page you need

in your case (assuming your root page is /)

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```